# Why is the airbrush grease pencil path so weird?

Tags: grease-pencil, layers

[image]

I am trying to add some soft shading by using airbrush, yet the brush path is so weird that there is no transparency in overlapping stroke. Is there something wrong with the setting?

Related tutorial:
(start from 16:17)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1038&v=kX9alavzPzc&feature=emb_logo

Comment: HI, it's better to just ask one question per post, thanks. Regarding the main question, what do you mean by "so weird"? can you try to describe the difference between what you get compared to what you expected?

Comment: Understood, thanks for letting me know. The "weird" thing is that the airbrush does not work normally. The brush path is supposed to be overlapped other path, however, there is a visible path of the brown airbrush now.

Comment: right, now I get it! don't know the solution but maybe edit your question to include something along the lines of "no transparency in overlapping stroke" and someone might be able to help

Comment: Edited, that's the situation I have encountered but not yet solved.

Comment: i think i worked it out, in the material tab try changing the `Mode Type` from `Line` to `Dots`. you might have to play around with the layer's opacity to get the same result as you had, but it won't leave the white edge marks

Comment: Solved, thanks for being so helpful!!

Comment: cool, posted it as an answer since it might be useful to someone else

Answer (score 0):

In the material tab change the `Mode Type` from `Line` to `Dots` to get stroke edges that blend properly when they overlap